# locking at same time vs one by one Dining philosphers

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking, dining-philosopher

What is the difference between locking at same time vs one by one in dining philospher
that is `lock(lck1, lck2)` vs `lck1.lock() lck2.lock()` ? I have tried both of them they are working fine. I have read about `lock(lck1, lck2)`  this way we can prevent deadlocks. As if one is acquired other not then it will release the acquired one and try again to acquire deadlocks. But what would be the impact of `lock(lck1, lck2)`  this here will it have something to related to performance. Please help i am new to multithreading.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <thread>
    #include <functional>
    #include <chrono>
    #include <vector>
    #include <mutex>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    class DiningPhilosophers {
    private:
        mutex mtx[5];
        
    public:
        DiningPhilosophers() { }
        
        void wantsToEat(int philosopher, function<void()> pickLeftFork, function<void()> pickRightFork, function<void()> eat, function<void()> putLeftFork, function<void()> putRightFork) {
            int left = philosopher;
            int right = (philosopher + 1) % 5;
            
            unique_lock<mutex> lck1(mtx[left], defer_lock); // defer_lock: init lck1 without locking mtx
            unique_lock<mutex> lck2(mtx[right], defer_lock);
            
            if (philosopher % 2 == 0) {
                // lck1.lock(); // do NOT use std::lock(lck1, lck2)
                // lck2.lock();
                lock(lck1, lck2);
                pickLeftFork(); pickRightFork();
            } else {
                lck2.lock();
                lck1.lock();
                pickLeftFork(); pickRightFork();
            }
            eat(); putRightFork(); putLeftFork();
            // lck1 & lck2 are auto released after this line
        }
    };
    
    void testPhilosopher(int philosopherId, DiningPhilosophers& diningPhilosophers) {
        // Lambda functions to simulate the actions of a philosopher
        auto pickLeftFork = [=]() { cout << "Philosopher " << philosopherId << " picked left fork." << endl; };
        auto pickRightFork = [=]() { cout << "Philosopher " << philosopherId << " picked right fork." << endl; };
        auto eat = [=]() {
            cout << "Philosopher " << philosopherId << " is eating." << endl;
            // Simulate eating time
            this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(500));
        };
        auto putLeftFork = [=]() { cout << "Philosopher " << philosopherId << " put down left fork." << endl; };
        auto putRightFork = [=]() { cout << "Philosopher " << philosopherId << " put down right fork." << endl; };
    
        // Call the wantsToEat function for the philosopher
        diningPhilosophers.wantsToEat(philosopherId, pickLeftFork, pickRightFork, eat, putLeftFork, putRightFork);
    }
    
    int main() {
        DiningPhilosophers diningPhilosophers;
    
        // Create five threads, each representing a philosopher
        vector<thread> philosopherThreads;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
            philosopherThreads.emplace_back(testPhilosopher, i, ref(diningPhilosophers));
        }
    
        // Wait for all threads to finish
        for (auto& thread : philosopherThreads) {
            thread.join();
        }
    
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: If your question really is "what is the difference?" you seem to be answering that in your question.  One form will avoid deadlocks, regardless of the parameter order.

Comment: Can you please provide the reference doc which provide details of the difference between too ? @DrewDormann

Comment: It is easy to write code that is incorrect but handles all of your test cases, and the fewer the test cases you use, the easier it gets.

Comment: Code that is written such that multiple locks do not deadlock does not have to worry about using a mult-lock to avoid deadlocks.

Comment: Your code **can** deadlock.  I'd be happy to explain how, but not in a comment.  If reopened, and no one else does, I'd be happy to answer.  In the meantime, here's a link which explores the performance of different ways to implement `std::lock`: http://howardhinnant.github.io/dining_philosophers.html

Comment: Have at it, @HowardHinnant

Answer (score 2):

My comment under the question *may* be an exaggeration, I'm honestly not sure.  However I can say for sure that if your code locked each mutex in the same relative order (left then right or vice-versa) then dead lock is virtually guaranteed if you have a high enough number of iterations of eating.

*Explanation:*

Let's presume that each philosopher locked the left mutex first and then the right mutex.  If they all did this simultaneously, then they would all succeed in getting their left mutex, and then they would all block on trying to obtain the right mutex.  This case is fairly easy to analyze.

As you create more complex locking patterns, the situation gets more complex to analyze.  And as this happens, it becomes more likely that the analyst will accidentally miss a scenario where deadlock might occur.  It is also typical in such scenarios that the deadlock becomes much more infrequent.

This is not a good thing.

The worst case scenario is when you falsely convince yourself that no deadlock could occur, and testing doesn't reveal it because the probability of it happening is so low.  So you ship the code and it deadlocks 2 years later in the field.  Debugging something like that is the stuff of nightmares.

The best thing to do is to use a foolproof system.  One such foolproof system for simultaneously locking more than 1 mutex is `std::lock`, or its C++17 equivalent, `std::scoped_lock<Mutex1, Mutex2, ...>` (which simply calls `std::lock` in its member function `lock()`).

`std::lock(lck1, lck2)` will *never* deadlock (unless misused by locking those locks elsewhere without `std::lock`).

[Here is a paper](http://howardhinnant.github.io/dining_philosophers.html) which explores the performance of various algorithms for implementing `std::lock`.  This is an interesting read if you believe that always locking your locks in some predefined order is the best way to go.  Locking in order is a good tool in the toolbox.  However it is sub-optimal algorithm for `std::lock` as shown in the paper.

As I write this answer, all implementations of `std::lock` I'm aware of (MSVC, gcc, llvm) have a very high-performing implementation.<sup>1</sup>  So using `std::lock` is the smart move when the alternative is trying to figure out if your fancy pattern of locking multiple locks has the potential for deadlock or not.

---

<sup>1</sup> The paper says this about the "Persistent" algorithm:

> No one that I'm aware of has seriously proposed this algorithm as a good solution. However it is included here as there is at least one shipping implementation of `std::lock` that implements this exact algorithm.

The implementations have vastly improved in the nine years since this paper was written.

Comment: After three and a half weeks in the middle of bug-infested, butt<expletive deleted> nowhere trying to trap a deadlock I was on the plane back home when it locked up. The client had insisted that I remove all of the diagnostics and tracking code before I left, so I came away with nothing and got sent right back in for another two weeks. The stuff of nightmares indeed.